# Mimicking (*office) CV-layout in TeX

Tags: tables, boxes, resume

To me (who considers himself a TeX-beginner for a long while to come) it seems like quite a mountain to climb, with much guessworking required, to convert this CV template into a (reasonably close, or better) TeX equivalent:

[image]

My guess is that http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes might come in handy, and/or knowledge of tables.

Would much appreciate some ideas, maybe it's a piece of cake for the TeX-gurus out there?

Comment: Do you necessarily care about fonts?

Comment: if possible please add [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that has been tried so as to help others build on.

Comment: @SeanAllred the above example uses [Calibri](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96993/how-to-use-the-calibri-font) mainly and for the title Cambria, I think. -- Minion, Myriad and Pragmata seem to be pretty, too. So yes, I'd be happy to replicate/mimick this template close to 1:1, but the font consideration is secondary I'd say...

Comment: @SeanAllred btw, thanks for the hint of using `mdframed`. Am just wondering if that's considered a "state-of-the-art" pkg, or if it has some "competitors", as it were: do you know of any? e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71554/framed-or-mdframed-pros-cons

Comment: From Marco's answer: "Nobody can help you with the decision." ;-)  At the end of the day, `mdframed` is what I saw being used around here for fancy shtuff, and I figured this Q was a good excuse to learn a little about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not consider myself a TeX-guru (TeXpert), but I think I see where this can go.

Mostly, this is an application of `mdframed`, mildly fancy `tabular` usage (with some support from `multirow` and friends thrown in), and a good knowledge of how environments work in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\usepackage{anyfontsize,multirow,mwe}

\newenvironment{infobox}[2][green]{%
  \begin{mdframed}[%
    skipabove=4ex plus .5ex minus .5ex,%
    skipbelow=4ex plus .5ex minus .5ex,%
    frametitle={\sffamily #2},%
    innertopmargin=2ex,%
    innerbottommargin=2ex,%
    frametitleaboveskip=1.618ex,%
    frametitlebelowskip=1.618ex,%
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=#1,%
    linecolor=#1]%
}{%
  \end{mdframed}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont
  \sffamily
  \scshape
  \color{green!50!black}
  Some Name
\end{center}
\begin{infobox}[green!80!black]{\textcolor{white}{Personal Data}}
  \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{1cm}
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \multirow{7}{*}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}} & Date of Birth & 22 February 2002 \\
    & a & b \\
    & a & b \\
    &   &   \\
    & a & b \\
    & a & b \\
    & a & b \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{infobox}

\begin{infobox}[green!80!black]{Title!!}
  \begin{list}{...}{...}
    \item[...] ...
  \end{list}
\end{infobox}
\end{document}
```

Note: you probably don't want to use the minimal class.  I'm just trying to show all of the dependencies of this way.  This can also be made *much* simpler when it comes time to using the environment if and when you settle on a *consistent* format.  (Note that the example you provide is ***not*** consistent when it comes to what a `description` is.)

See what you can do with it.

[image: output]

Comment: Things to settle down in the `infobox` environment and beyond: the color of your table titles, the color of your tables, how you want to format descriptions.  I would also reconsider how you logically interpret your personal information --- it's not *really* a table, is it?  As far as that's concerned, take a look into `enumitem`.

Comment: Am not too sure about what you mean by *"consistent"* format. Do you mean that the three "boxes" shown are all "different" / differently organized? The remaining "boxes" are (mostly) organized in two columns: date (right-aligned) and content (left aligned). What else is deemed "in-consistent"? (suggestions for stylistically/typographically *improving* this template are welcomed, too!

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty In your example, there are several different iterations of what appears to be a `description` (although the very last seems to be a timeline; I would consider looking at `moderntimeline` ([pictures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83571))).  A CV/resume is very much up to personal taste though, so do what you think looks best; the example you provide looks like an abuse of tables, and this can easily be replicated in LaTeX (as I've shown).

Comment: still not too sure what you mean by `description`: is that supposed to denote a technical (TeX-)term? Or just me actually trying to literally *describe* "something" ? `description` (that is, a description of the tasks I had at a given post and the things I contributed/accomplished there) as opposed to just dropping / listing names of previous employers?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty as in `\begin{description}...\end{description}` --- you declare to LaTeX that this is a `description` and LaTeX (or you) decide(s) how to represent a `description` (if this *happens* to be in the form of a table, so be it, but to me it looks a little awkward).

Comment: as in http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#Description

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty indeed.  As your document matures (you can hack it together in tables for now if you want), I would think more on how your document is actually *structured* before thinking about how it *looks*.  Such care will produce a much more consistent document.  (If you'd like, I can give mine as an example once I censor the *mounds* of sensitive information.)

Comment: (this is getting a bit long, but I might delete some of the above to "make space") a) there's no rush (the *office-template is still "operational"), b) I totally agree that it ought to be well-structured and TeX-optimized (else it wouldn't even make sense to attempt the migration from *office), c) appreciate all input / examples :-)

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty Just things to think about - sometimes it gets a little weird migrating a 'conventional' document over to TeX-world... separating structure and format is even harder post-hoc :-)